Proof that a particular quantity is not the limit of a function.
I want to use the notation ε-δ and the definition of the limit of a function according to Cauchy to strictly show that if some quantity depends on the same variable as the function under study, then it cannot be the limit of this function. But I have encountered a problem in this and I want to show what it consists of using a specific example.
Let us consider the function $y$ : $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$, which is defined by the analytical expression $y=x+4$ and consider the limit of this function as x approaches 0. Now we will deliberately take a false limit value $(4+2x)$ and check whether the necessary conditions for it are satisfied. According to the definition for $0<|x|<δ$ we get the inequality $|x+4-(4+2x)|<ε$ . As a result, the second inequality will have the form  $|-x|=|x|<ε$ .  From this moment it is quite understandable that if we take $δ$ less than or equal to $ε$, then the corresponding inequality will be satisfied, for example $δ=\frac{ε}{2}$.
I had an idea to prove that this quantity is not a limit by finding such $ε>0$ that there would be no value $δ>0$ for it for which the inequality would be satisfied. But as you can see, the inequality $|x|<ε$ is symmetric with respect to the point $x=0$ and thus is satisfied for all possible values of $ε$.
I understand that the limit must be unique and thus a constant number, but why does such a situation arise that if we take a value that depends on a variable, then all the necessary conditions are formally met for it, as for a true limit? Perhaps there are some criteria that would allow us to strictly show that such quantities are not limits?

Do you think that the limit of a function $y=x+4$  when $x \to 0$  is a function $y=4+2x$?

No, I'm looking for a way to prove that it's a false statement.

In the usual understanding of the limit of a function this is already false since the limit of a function is a number.

I agree, but why are the necessary conditions for the existence of a limit be satisfied for this false limit? I would like to prove rigorously in terms of ε-δ that the quantity (4+2x) is not a limit.

the limit of a function as $x\to 0$ is a number (not a function), provided the limit exists. Many different functions can have the same number as their limit as $x\to 0$. You give two examples where the limit is the number $0$.

This has nothing to do with deltas and epsilons. When you write $\lim_{x\to0}(x+4)=4+2x$, the $x$ on the left side is a dummy variable – nothing would change on the left side if you wrote $\lim_{t\to0}(t+4)$ or $\lim_{George\to0}(George+4)$. The $x$ on the right side is not a dummy variable; $4+2x$ is not the same thing as $4+2t$, as you will see immediately if you evaluate both expressions at, say, $x=17$. So, $\lim_{x\to0}(x+4)=4+2x$ is a nonsense, because $x$ is a dummy variable on the left, but a genuine variable on the right.
